# what is wrong in my this vb.net code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim lab As Label = Me.GridView1.FindControl("Label1")
        If TextBox2.Text = "7" Then
            GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text = "500"
        Else
            GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(2).Text = "950"
        End If
    End Sub
```

The following error occurs : ***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

Comment: What line are you getting the error at? Is it possible that there is no selected row when the page first loads and hence  `GridView1.SelectedRow` might be null ?

Comment: ya i want i want to display rates from my self ... another rated for another id nos...

Comment: Do you ever set `GridView1.SelectedRow`?

Comment: I think Phillip Fourie is correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got this code in your Page Load event, so it will run when the page is first loaded, and on every single postback. This probably isn't what you want.

I imagine that on the very first load, there isn't a selected row in your GridView, so `GridView1.SelectedRow` is going to be `null`. If this isn't null, then `Cells` or `Cells(2)` definitely will be. Trying to access a property on null is going to throw a NullReferenceException - "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

As this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx) shows, you're probably better off accessing the SelectedRow property in an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim lab As Label = Me.GridView1.FindControl("Label1")
```

It doesn't look like you're doing anything with this label. Put a breakpoint on that line and see if it finds it. If it doesn't and you don't even use it, take the line out.

Also, check if textbox2 is valid whilst debugging.